# Investigation of MSIL code

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I'm working with IL code now and will need to write by myself in the future. There are some concerns I have because of misunderstanding. Here is a simple method in C#

```
public static string Method1(int id)
 {
   return Method2(id);
 }
```

and here is its IL code

```
.method public hidebysig static string 
          Method1(int32 id) cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init ([0] string CS$1$0000)
    IL_0000:  nop          // Why?
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  call       string MyNamespace.MyClass::Method2(int32)
    IL_0007:  stloc.0    // storing a return value of MyClass::Method2 to local variable.
    IL_0008:  br.s       IL_000a   // Why?

    IL_000a:  ldloc.0    // Does it really require and why?
    IL_000b:  ret
  } // end of method MyClass::Method1
```

**Each** method in CIL has `nop` operation for some reason. Why does it have it?
In my case, is it necessary to use `br.s  IL_000a` and will it working without it?

Comment: "write by myself", are you gonna write IL?

Comment: I've posted what the IL *should* be as an edit on peer's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nops are there to allow you to debug (set breakpoint), if you compile in release mode you will see less nopes in your code.

If you compile the same code in release/optimized mode, the IL should look much saner:

```
.method public hidebysig static string Method1(int32 id) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: call string MyNamespace.MyClass::Method2(int32)
    L_0006: ret 
}
```

Comment: I edited in what it would look like in a release build - hope you don't mind. You covered the key points, so a second answer seemed redundant.

Comment: Marc, thank you, it's more clear now. However why is .maxstack equal to 8?

Comment: And one more thing: I don't have to use L_00XX: instructions, do I?